# set javascript variable from an ajax request globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax code right here:

```
<script>
    $('a[data-id]').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var domain = $(this).attr('data-domain');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getdata',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: id, domain: domain},
            success: function (data) {
                var domains = data.name + data.tld;
                var tld = data.tld;
                $('.resultdomain').html(domains);

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code works but my problem is that I want to set the tld variable globally to use them in an if statement.

I want to use the variable like this in my code:

```
if(tld == .de)
{
document.write('<img src="imagelink.png" alt="denic" class="pull-right">')
}
elseif(tld == .com)
{
document.write('<img src="otherimagelink.png" alt="core" class="pull-right">')
}
```

but I couldn't figure out how I can set the tld variable globally to use it everywhere in my code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try declaring the variable globally instead of as a local variable? (Noting that ajax is asynchronous, so you couldn't actually use the value in the global variable until after the success callback runs.)

Comment: well, I tried something like that but wasn't really successfull. I don't really worked alot with JS..

Answer (score 1):

try defining `tdl` variable globally out of the scope

```
<script>
      var tdl;
      $('a[data-id]').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var domain = $(this).attr('data-domain');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getdata',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: id, domain: domain},
            success: function (data) {
                var domains = data.name + data.tld;
                tld = data.tld;
                $('.resultdomain').html(domains);
                 if(tld == .de)
                 {
                    document.write('<img src="imagelink.png" alt="denic" class="pull-right">')
                 }
                 elseif(tld == .com)
                 {
                    document.write('<img src="otherimagelink.png" alt="core" class="pull-right">')
                 }
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: if I'm trying to use the variable in my if statement, just nothing happen

Comment: @WellNo check with your if statement when the data loaded

Comment: I've did a document.ready around the if statement but it still did nothing. The ajax code is at the bottom of my code. The if statemant at the top. Between them are about 300 lines of code, thats why I need to get the tld variable global.

Comment: the problem is not tdl here, before your ajax request success your global tdl variable is null

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `tld` variable is enclosed in your AJAX call. It is only available to use within the scope of its definition. I've moved it outside of your AJAX call.

```
   <script>
        var tld;
        $('a[data-id]').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var domain = $(this).attr('data-domain');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getdata',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {id: id, domain: domain},
                success: function (data) {
                    var domains = data.name + data.tld;
                    tld = data.tld;
                    $('.resultdomain').html(domains);

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work. If I console.log(tld) i'm getting the right output. If I use that in my code - like if(tld == .de) {... } nothing happen

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. Have you set a breakpoint on `tld = data.tld;`? I think it should be `tld = data.data.tld;`

Comment: I think tld = data.tld is enough cause I get the right output if I'm trying to console.log it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check strings, not `.de` but `".de"`

```
    if(tld == ".de")
    {
        document.write('<img src="imagelink.png" alt="denic" class="pull-right">')
    }
    elseif(tld == ".com")
    {
        document.write('<img src="otherimagelink.png" alt="core" class="pull-right">')
    }
```

Comment: yes, I have that like this in my code. I just wrote the if statement for an example quick in the question box

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(tld)` to check real value of this variable?

Comment: I did and in tld is the right value. But I can't use it everywhere in my code

Comment: In your if statement add `console.log(tld)` before each `document.write(...)`. You should be able to see value of that variable. I think `document.write()` is messed up.